# CSS & HTML overlay moves slightly when opening nav menu on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar, overlay

I'm using CSS, HTML and Javascript with bootstrap functions to create a responsive navbar menu that turns to a burger menu when on smaller screens. Then when you click the burger menu, a full-screen overlay appears with the menu items.

What's happening though is that the elements within the overlay move a couple of pixels to the top when clicking on it, so the logo "PENELOPE ATKINSON" and the burger menu/cross move up a little.

Does anyone know how I can fix this so the elements in the overlay menu don't move? would be greatly appreciated!

In addition to bootstrap files, I will paste the files I'm using below because I'm not sure how else to share it on here.

**test.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/browser_logo/browser_logo.png">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--NAV BAR-->
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-mobileMenu d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center gx-5 mt-4">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo overlay-color" onclick="closeNav()">PENELOPE ATKINSON</a>
            <a href="#" class="closebtn overlay-menu-color" onclick="closeNav()">
                <img alt="cross" src="icons/cross.svg">
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-menu">
            <ul class="no-bullets">
                <li><a href="graphic-design.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="uxui-design.html">UX/UI DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center gx-5 mt-4">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo">PENELOPE ATKINSON</a>
        <ul class="desktopMenu no-bullets">
            <li><a href="graphic-design.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="uxui-design.html">UX/UI DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="mobileMenu" onclick="openNav()">
            <img alt="burger-menu" src="icons/burger-menu.svg">
        </a>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function openNav(){
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav(){
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

window.onload = function() {

    var pageTitle = document.title;
    var attentionMessage = 'Come back!';
    var blinkEvent = null;
  
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
      var isPageActive = !document.hidden;
  
      if(!isPageActive){
        blink();
      }else {
        document.title = pageTitle;
        clearInterval(blinkEvent);
      }
    });
  
    function blink(){
      blinkEvent = setInterval(function() {
        if(document.title === attentionMessage){
          document.title = pageTitle;
        }else {
          document.title = attentionMessage;
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  };
```

**styles.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=News%20Cycle&display=swap');
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/uzc8mug.css");
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Baptiste-Regular';
    src: url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.svg#Baptiste-Regular') format('svg'),
            url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
            url('/fonts/Baptiste-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

* {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.padding-main img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh ;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    }

body {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    font-family: 'acumin-pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    }  

p { 
    text-indent: 10rem;
    margin: 0;  
 }

 p:first-of-type {
    text-indent: 0;
  }

.larger-text {
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.left-side-text {
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    left: 1%;
    top: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.right-side-text {
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    top: 45%;
    right: -4%;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.padding-main {
    padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    }

.padding-text {
    padding: 0 8vw;
}

.padding-top{
    padding-top: 15vh;
    }

.pb-6 {
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
}

.pb-8 {
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    }

.homescreen-intro {
    font-family: 'Baptiste-Regular', serif;
    font-size: 9rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 48vh 0 0 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.about-intro {
    font-family: 'Baptiste-Regular', serif;
    font-size: 7rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10vh 0 10vh 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.project-intro {
    font-family: 'Baptiste-Regular', serif;
    font-size: 7rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 7vh 0 7vh 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.about-text {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.contact-info {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.white {color: white!important;}

.mt-6 {
    margin-top: 6rem; 
}

.mt-7 {
    margin-top: 7rem; 
}

.mt-8 {
    margin-top: 8rem; 
}

.mt-9 {
    margin-top: 9rem; 
}

.mt-10 {
    margin-top: 10rem; 
}

.pe-6 {
    padding-right: 8rem; 
}

.pb-6 {
    padding-bottom: 8rem; 
}

.pb-7 {
    padding-bottom: 7rem; 
}

.pb-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10rem; 
}

hr {
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    opacity: 1;
    
}

.asterisk {
    vertical-align: -30%;
    font-size: 14rem;
}

div h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }

.no-bullets {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.about-icons {
    font-size: 7rem;
    line-height: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    vertical-align: -40%;
}

.icons {
    font-family: monospace; 
}

.underline-dot {
    text-decoration: underline dotted 2px; 
    text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
    color: black;
}

.underline-solid {
    text-decoration: underline 2px; 
    text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
    color: black;
}

.styled li {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    text-indent: -1rem;
    }

ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}

ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}

.keep-together {
    white-space: nowrap ;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    }

a:visited {
    color: black;
    }

.page_active {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.pic {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.imgtext {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: light;
    font-size: 2rem;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

h1::before { 
    display: block; 
    content: " "; 
    margin-top: -200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    pointer-events: none;
    }

.image_gallery {
    object-fit: cover;
    }

.align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    }

.align-bottom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0 0;
    }

.row.display-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

.footer {
    align-items: left;
    padding: 10vh 0 10vh 0;
    background-color: #E8E7DE;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    }

.footer ul {
    padding:0;
}

.margin-top{
    margin-top: 40vh;
    }

.g-10{
    padding: 5rem;
}

/* NAVBAR - main */
.navbar {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.desktopMenu li {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.mobileMenu{
    display: none; 
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}

/* NAVBAR - overlay */
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    background-color: #E8E7DE;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.closebtn{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 3.5rem;
    padding: 0;
    display:block; 
}
.overlay-mobileMenu-color {
    filter: invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(20%) hue-rotate(324deg) brightness(106%) contrast(105%);
}
.overlay-color {
    color:  black !important;    
}
.overlay-mobileMenu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay-menu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay-menu li {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.overlay-menu li a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.overlay-mobileMenu .mobile, .navbar .mobile {
    display: none;
}

.full-width-image {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }


@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {

    .pic:hover .right-side-text {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .pic:hover .left-side-text {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline solid 1px;
        text-decoration-thickness: 0.1rem;
        text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
        color: black;
    }

    .prototype:hover {
        filter: brightness(107%);
      }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

    .padding-main{
        padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    }

    .margin-main {
        margin-left: 2.5rem;
        margin-right: 2.5rem;
    }

    .margin-top{
        margin-top: 15vh;
    }

    /* NAVBAR - main */
    .mobileMenu{
        display: block;
        height: 3rem;
        width: 3rem;
    }

    .desktopMenu {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    
    .overlay-mobileMenu .mobile, .navbar .mobile {
        display: block;
    }
    .overlay-mobileMenu .desktop, .navbar .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .homescreen-intro {
        margin-top: 10vh;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .asterisk {
        vertical-align: -30%;
        font-size: 9rem;
        line-height: 11rem;
        height: 9rem;
    }
        
    .footer {
        align-items: left;
        padding: 8vh 0 8vh 0;
        background-color: #F3F2E9;
    }

    .align-center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .align-center ul { 
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .footer-list li {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

}  


.gx-5 {
    padding-left: 5rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I solved it by using py-5 instead of mt-5! Not sure how that solves it but it did and I'm happy :D